# fatal error while using Java3d on newer ubuntu version than 11.10

Tags: java, openjdk

I'm running a java based website where i use java3d to render some 3d images without any problem on oneiric.

I also need to say since the application runs on a server without a graphiccard, i use xvfb.

When i'm doing a system upgrade (i tried every version up to 14.10) i get following fatal error.

I tried a lot of different setups. oracle java, openjdk in all versions, no luck.

what puzzles me most is, the first rendering is working, sometimes the second. but after then it kills the whole java process and i see following error message in the logs:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f3f2e91a530, pid=9831, tid=139909307741952
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (7.0_65-b32) (build 1.7.0_65-b32)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (24.65-b04 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Derivative: IcedTea 2.5.3
# Distribution: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, package 7u71-2.5.3-0ubuntu0.14.04.1
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libGL.so.1+0x3d530]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /home/litwan/8080yanel/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.25/bin/hs_err_pid9831.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please include
# instructions on how to reproduce the bug and visit:
#   http://icedtea.classpath.org/bugzilla
#
```

Any help or hint would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution!

Update to java3d 1.6. as seen here:
https://gouessej.wordpress.com/2012/08/01/java-3d-est-de-retour-java-3d-is-back/

BTW it is very important to clean up/uninstall  your old java3d before.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tested with several distros including Mageia Linux 4, it should work flawlessly with Ubuntu. In March 2015, you might have to stick to JOGL 2.2 with Java 3D until the next build of Java3D is compatible with JOGL 2.3.0 (probably next month). Good luck.